# How to access "Apps with usage access" setting on LG G3?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, settings, lg-g3

I have an LG G3 with Android 5.0, but I can't find this setting.
I read it's in Privacy → Security, but the setting doesn't seem to be there:

[image: screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click for larger variant)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

It seems that **LG removed the entry to the setting on LG G3**. Whether it's accidental or not, it's unclear.

There are many reports stating the same issue:

- on [LG G3 Sub-Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/lgg3/comments/30m67j/question_for_anyone_who_has_a_lg_g3_with_lollipop/)

  > I have an app that asks me to go to "Apps with Usage Access". The app instructions tell me to go here: "Settings >> General >> Security >> Apps that access Usage Data". I am not exactly able to find it. My question is -- does your LG G3 with Lollipop have an option called "Apps that access Usage Data"?
- by [Mark on Google+](https://plus.google.com/+MarkClydesdale/posts/gDpRFdFrxN1)

  > I'm using an LG G3 and since I got the Lollipop update I haven't been able to use the LAS app.
  >   I noticed the app (was) updated and requires to change 'Apps with usage access'. Unfortunately on my phone I don't see the option. I have installed on my Nexus 7 and made the required change and works perfectly again. Does anyone know how to change/access on a LG G3?
- both on [AndroidForums](http://androidforums.com/threads/apps-with-usage-access-error.911118/) and [AndroidCentral](http://forums.androidcentral.com/lg-g3/507009-apps-usage-access-error-message.html) by same user (which has sligthly different issue)

  > Any time I restart my phone I get an error because of Smart Clean, it apparently resets itself & that interferes with Llama, and I need to go & toggle Smart Clean off again. Does anyone know if I can get to the screen below without going from an error message?
- on [AutomateIt's FAQ](http://automateitapp.com/faq-support/)

  > Due to changes in Android Lollipop, In order for AutomateIt to monitor active apps it requires an explicit permission from the user. You can do that by going to your device **Settings**→**Security** and click on the “**Apps with usage access option**” (This should be the last item on the settings screen). On some devices, that option is not present (such as LG G3) and on those devices, the “Application State Trigger” **cannot be supported**.
- on [MobileSyrup Community](http://community.mobilesyrup.com/topic/i-have-an-lg-g4-ask-me-anything/)

  > On stock Android, this can be found in Settings > Security > Apps with usage access. This is absent from the G3 running Lollipop.
- on [RescueTime's Blog](http://blog.rescuetime.com/2015/02/06/lgs-build-of-android-5-lollipop-for-the-g3-is-missing-core-os-libraries/)

  > It appears that LG has pushed out a variant build of Android 5 missing an entire library that is part of the SDK specification for build level 21 (Android 5), the [**“android.app.usage” API**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/package-summary.html).

---

**Possible workaround:**

- Download an app that needs this setting to be switched on (e.g. based on the forum post, [Llama](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kebab.Llama)).
- Use custom ROM that implements this feature (e.g. based on Reddit's post, [CyanogenMod 12](http://www.cyanogenmod.org/))

Answer (score 0):

You can access this setting by downloading Nova Launcher from the play store. Once installed hold down on any empty place until the add options coome up. Then click on activities and drag it to an empty place on screen. Now a list of activities will be displayed. Scroll down to settings and click on it. Now scroll down to apps with usage access. Hold it for a few seconds and the apps with usage access screen will open.

Answer (score 0):

There's an app on Google Play called "QuickShortcutMaker" and it not only allows you to make shortcuts to anything sort of like Nova does, but also access any setting via a search function, including settings that are hidden in your ROM, for example if you're using a Chinese phone. That's how I get around hidden options on my ZTE.

Answer (score 0):

On my LG K92 and Lenovo Duet (Chromebook), I had to search for "special app access". Then choose "usage access" and you'll be taken to a list of apps. Choose your app and change settings appropriately.